# Is it "Myself and _____", "_____ and myself", or "____ and I"?

Tags: british-english

For example, "Lucy and I are going to a movie" vs. "Myself and Lucy are going to a movie" vs. "Lucy and myself are going to a movie"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You'd probably find more help at https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The general rule of politeness is that you place yourself last in a list of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lucy and I" are the subject of this sentence. Thus, it would be **"Lucy and I are going to a movie"**. You wouldn't use "myself" because this is a reflexive pronoun.

Comment: That's not what actual people actually do, though. Not in English they don't. Which is kind of the whole reason why this question exists in the first place.

Comment: @RegDwigнt is correct: actual people, native speakers of English, do say "Myself  and Lucy are going to the cinema". They also say "Me and Lucy are going to the cinema". The first of those might be a result of some school teacher long ago saying that to use "I" is impolite - but who knows. Grammarians might hate those usages. I hate them. But nobody can deny that they are current, even with educated native speakers.

Comment: @JeremyC Very interesting. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

The reflexive pronoun should not be in the subject of a sentence unless it is used as an intensifier, accompanied by another noun or pronoun:

```
I, myself, am going to the movie.
```

In the above, the sense conveyed might be: *I'm not sending someone else to the movie [to write a review], I'm doing it personally!*

This isn't the case in your example, so the correct choice is:

```
Lucy and I are going to the movie.
```

Comment: I see. Could you replace "personally" with "myself", in your sentence?

Comment: In the sentence “Myself and Lucy are going to the cinema”, the reflexive pronoun _myself_ **is** accompanied by another noun or pronoun: _Lucy_. Traditionalist, prescriptive grammarians from the 19th century would obviously frown on such usage, but it is a natural part of current English as she is spoke.

Comment: Yes, but Lucy isn’t intensified by *myself*.  This isn’t like splitting an infinitive or ending a sentence with a preposition.  People do speak this way, but people make grammatical mistakes and sound less educated because of them.  This is akin to saying “Me and Lucy...”. People speak that way, but it’s still generally accepted as wrong.